# Networking on IOS using Alamofire

Tags: swift, xcode, api, networking, alamofire

I’m an IOS developer. I have a new client who wants me to teach him about Alamofire and the networking stuff, and to be honest, i’m bad at teaching.
so, can anyone suggest me a book or any tutorial that i can follow during the lecture?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Alamofire**

- https://www.raywenderlich.com/35-alamofire-tutorial-getting-started
- https://codewithchris.com/alamofire/
- https://learnappmaking.com/alamofire-swift-tutorial/

**iOS Networking**

- https://learnappmaking.com/urlsession-swift-networking-how-to/
- https://www.udacity.com/course/ios-networking-with-swift--ud421

Don't forget to check out official documentation as well.